# Is this probability possible to calculate from the given ones?

Tags: probability

GIVEN:

(B) = 0.1

(A|B) = 0.8

(A|¬B) = 0.2

QUESTION:
What is P(A)?

I know P(A∧B) = (A|B)(B) = 0.08 but I can't figure out how to get P(A) from that and the given probabilities.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Find $P(A\wedge B)$ exactly as you describe.

Find $P(A\wedge \neg B)$ in a similar fashion.

What is $P(A\wedge B)+P(A\wedge \neg B)$?  (*not just in terms of value, but in terms of what it represents*)

Answer (score 2):

Use the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability): $$P(A)=P(A|B)P(B)+P(A|\neg B)P(\neg B)$$
where $P(\neg B)=1-P(B)$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$
P(A) = P(A \cap B) + P(A \cap \lnot B) = P(A|B) P(B) + P(A|\lnot B) P(\lnot B)
$$
and you know all the probabilities on the right hand side.